# chaining api in componentWillMount - async await or promise

Tags: reactjs

so after login , i will have some values in the cookie which i need to set to the redux and then call another api. So after login i will have name in cookie. so i will take the name value and set in the redux once it is done i will clear the name from the cookie. and after clearing the values i need to fetch the name set in redux and pass the name to call another api in componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.props.setDetailsToRedux()
  clearCookie()
  this.props.anotherApiCall(this.props.currentUser.name)

}
```

so how can i do this should i use async await. And how can i use it

Comment: Did you actually try async/await before asking? What was a problem? Also, componentWillMount was deprecated because it's misused like that most times. This code belongs to componentDidMount.

Comment: Why don't you set that name in login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async/await` in your React lifecycle methods. Just remember to add async to the function:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const someValue = await doFirstThing()
        await doSomethingWithValue(someValue)
    }
```

If your render method depends on the status of this process, add some local state:

```
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            isReady: false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const someValue = await doFirstThing()
        await doSomethingWithValue(someValue)
        this.setState({isReady: true})
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return null /* or a loader/spinner */
        }

        return "I'm loaded ok."
    }
```

Also make sure to read the other answers as they have valid concerns about your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `componentWillMount` is not the right place to make an API call, just use it in `componentDidMount`, instead.

**componentWillMount / UNSAFE_componentWillMount**

If you are seeing `UNSAFE_` for the first time, let me tell you in React v16.3.0 released a few days ago, it has been announced that `componentWillMount` will only work until version 17 and `UNSAFE_` will be prefixed to allow gradual migration. 
**This is a very strong reason to not to use this method**.

In past, there has been a big debate and discussion in React community to deprecate `componentWillMount` and use the `constructor` instead and hence that has been done.

This has been a very common misconception among the React developers in the community that we should call API in `componentWillMount` so that additional render can be prevented. But the truth is render method will always be immediately called after componentWillMount and **there is no way to ask render to wait for the API call to finish**.

Ref: https://hackernoon.com/where-to-integrate-api-calls-in-reactjs-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-710085dc05c3

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the name in cookie if you cleared the cookie after set the name in redux. you can directly set the name in redux from login after set in redux you will found the name anywhere from redux.